# Opening new a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to have a pop-out button, such that when it's clicked the current grid will appear in a new window populated with the exact same information.

I got the new Window to appear but I'm trying to have the bindings set but unsure how to do that. If I can get some help please. When I execute OpenChildWindow it opens but nothing populates.

Viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<PaymentInfo> AmortizationCollection {get; set;}
public void OpenChildWindow()
{
    new ScheduleView().Show();
}
```

LoanView.xaml and ScheduleView.xaml

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="AmortGrid" 
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll ="True" 
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     Height="650"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                     ShowGroupPanel="False"  
                     ItemsSource="{Binding AmortizationCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

My attempt at Content Setting

Scheduleview.xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<PaymentInfo> AmortizationCollection { get; set; } 
public ScheduleView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AmortGrid.ItemsSource = Content;
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public void OpenChildWindow()
{
     ScheduleView _newScheduleView = new ScheduleView();
     _newScheduleView.Content = AmortizationCollection;
     _newScheduleView.Show(); 
}
```

The window just appears (Collection) no datagrid or anyhting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using WPF, we tend to use `DataTemplate`s to define what our data objects look like in the UI, so to recreate some UI control, we just need to pass the data object and ensure that the `DataTemplate` is accessible from both locations. You show code from your 'view model', but view models shouldn't know anything about the views and certainly don't open new windows like that.

However, incorrect terminology aside, your simplest solution would be to simply pass the collection to the new `Window` in the constructor:

```
public void OpenChildWindow()
{
     ScheduleView _newScheduleView = new ScheduleView(AmortizationCollection);
     _newScheduleView.Show(); 
}
```

Then in `ScheduleView.xaml.cs`:

```
public ScheduleView(ObservableCollection<PaymentInfo> amortizationCollection)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AmortizationCollection = amortizationCollection;
    AmortGrid.ItemsSource = AmortizationCollection;
}
```

As long as you have the same XAML in each place, it should look the same.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a `Window` then you can try to set some Content to it, this way the new control that you'll pass will be set as the content of the new window. I think this property is missing in your code untill now.

```
// create instance
ScheduleView wind = new ScheduleView();
// set the content, can be a window or a page or anything
wind.Content = new SomeControl;
// show it.
wind.Show();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.content(v=vs.95).aspx

A previous thread from Stack Overflow has this, but in a manner that was too general.

[Changing content of Window (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909441/changing-content-of-window-wpf)

Comment: Hi Afzaal, I attempted at the content, tried break points but I'm still having alittle trouble.

Comment: Tried using : `_newScheduleView.Content = new AmortizationCollection;
`